# How to find tax type in tally xml export?

Tags: c#, xml, tally

I am new to TDL development I am using

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>
      Export Data
    </TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <EXPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
          <SVFROMDATE>
            20210101
          </SVFROMDATE>
          <SVTODATE>
            20210116
          </SVTODATE>
          <VOUCHERTYPENAME>
            Purchase
          </VOUCHERTYPENAME>
          <EXPLODEFLAG>
            Yes
          </EXPLODEFLAG>
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            $$SysName: XML
          </SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <REPORTNAME>
          Voucher Register
        </REPORTNAME>
      </REQUESTDESC>
    </EXPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

The above mention XML request successfully gives me the list of purchase voucher. All the invoice level information can be found in `ENVELOPE/BODY/IMPORTDATA/REQUESTDATA/TALLYMESSAGE` node. each `TALLYMESSAGE` node consist of all the invoice level information and comes with multiple `LEDGERENTRIES.LIST` nodes which then consist of multiple amount fro eg.

```xml
<LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
     <AMOUNT>123</AMOUNT>
</LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

<LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
     <AMOUNT>-12</AMOUNT>
</LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

<LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
     <AMOUNT>-12</AMOUNT>
</LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
```

These negative values denotes the tax amount but i am unable to find a way to identify the type of tax (CGST,IGST,SGST) in the voucher.
Is there any way to identify the type of tax.

Comment: Please post sample of input xml that contains the nodes you are havin issues with.

Comment: @jdweng here is the xml fro a single invoice with IGST tax in it and dont get confused by _LEDGERENTRIES.LIST/LEDGERNAME_  node as i can change that name from my tally itself. i am just looking for a way to identify the type of tax without looking into LEDGERNAME [link](
https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cb341373)

Comment: Did you check <LEDGERNAME>?

Comment: @jdweng thats what i am saying value of LEDGERNAME is not generic it can be changed from tally itself. i can cahnge the value from INPUT IGST to ANYTHING. Thats why i am looking for other identifiers.

Comment: I looked and don't see any identifiers set.  I assumed the tax rate is correct and maybe you don't need to types.  This is something that needs to be fixed when the xml file is generated.

Answer (score 0):

From Voucher XML we cannot Identify tax type of ledger as tally won't generate taxtype tag
for voucher ledgers
If you still want to known tax type of ledger then make a request to tally to get ledger details, you can find taxtype in
`<TAXTYPE TYPE="String">GST</TAXTYPE>`
Tag